Error with nativescript compilation due to gradle version change?
I have a nativescript project that is built through jenkins.
Up until July 9th, the project built without any issues. On that same day, and after a commit, the build stopped working.
To make sure that the error was not being caused by the new code, we reverted the changes, and the build was still not working.
After analysing the logs in detail, it seems that, when tns is processing the firebase plugin, it needs to download gradle.
When it does, it downloads gradle 8.4, and with that version the build does not work. In the logs from the working build, in the same day, gradle version being downloaded was 7.6.
It seems that one of the referenced components, such as nativescript-plugin-firebase, seem to be trying to use a version of gradle which is incompatible.
This is an excerpt of the compilation log from the working build:
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 10.8 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 1.13 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 13 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 27.1 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/classes/custom-translate-loader.ts] 438 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/classes/modal-helper/modal-dialog-parameters.ts] 967 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/backer-transform.ts] 1.1 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/budged-order-id.pipe.ts] 1.38 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/labels-transform.ts] 1.16 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/url-transform.ts] 1.45 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/auth/token.interceptor.ts] 6.42 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/localstorage-budget-order/localstorage-budget-order.service.ts] 10 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./environments/environment.ts] 1.3 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 2.71 KiB {bundle} [built]
    + 1367 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete.
nativescript-plugin-firebase: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ript_Application_Android_develop/platforms/android/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip

This is the nonworking build, which started happening later on july 9:
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 10.8 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 1.13 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 13 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 27.1 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/classes/custom-translate-loader.ts] 438 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/classes/modal-helper/modal-dialog-parameters.ts] 967 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/backer-transform.ts] 1.1 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/budged-order-id.pipe.ts] 1.38 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/labels-transform.ts] 1.16 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/customPipe/url-transform.ts] 1.45 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/auth/token.interceptor.ts] 6.42 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/localstorage-budget-order/localstorage-budget-order.service.ts] 10 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./environments/environment.ts] 1.3 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 2.71 KiB {bundle} [built]
    + 1367 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete.
nativescript-plugin-firebase: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ript_Application_Android_develop/platforms/android/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip

You can see in the last line of each of the logs, what version of gradle is being downloaded.
How can I make sure that I stick with the 7.6 version?
When this error is happening, first the build fails because the build requires java 17 instead of 11. If we install the version, the subsequent build error is:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'background_http'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
      > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.
        
        If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
   > Could not get unknown property 'generateReleaseBuildConfig' for root project 'background_http' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I have tried editing node_modules/nativescript/vendor/gradle-plugin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and inserted the last line:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip

When I do that, I get this error:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'background_http'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.4. Current version is 7.6. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in platforms/tempPlugin/background_http/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-8.4-all.zip

Thank you.

Did you manage to resolve this issue? I have the same. What version of NS do you have? Seems like somthing is forcing NS8 things. Same in mine, but can not figgure out what is forcing it.

@slejnej we are still working on a solution. We have been able to move past this error but still facing other issues. Will leave a solution here once we find it.

I have made some progress. If it helps anyone.
Create a patch-gradle.js file with contents:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// adjust your paths for nativescript-cli installed globally
const paths = [
  'GLOBAL/node_modules/nativescript/vendor/gradle-plugin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties',
  'GLOBAL/node_modules/nativescript/vendor/gradle-plugin/build.gradle',
  'node_modules/@nativescript/android/framework/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties',
  'node_modules/@nativescript/android/framework/build.gradle'
]
const finds = ["{{runtimeGradleVersion}}", "{{runtimeAndroidPluginVersion}}", '6.4', 'gradle:3.6.4']
// const replaces = ['6.7', '4.0.1'] // NS 7.1
const replaces = ['6.8', '4.1.2', '6.8', 'gradle:4.1.2'] // NS 7.2

// Define the path to the file
paths.forEach((value, key) => {
  const filePath = value;

  // Define the line to search and the replacement
  const lineToFind = finds[key];
  const lineToReplace = replaces[key];

  // Read the file content
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(`Error reading file: ${err}`);
    }

    // Replace the text in the line if it exists
    const updatedData = data.split('\n').map(line => {
      return line.includes(lineToFind) ? line.replace(lineToFind, lineToReplace) : line;
    }).join('\n');

    // Write the updated content back to the file
    fs.writeFile(filePath, updatedData, 'utf8', (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
      }
      console.log('File successfully updated!');
    });
  });
});

Then create platform tns platform add android.
Then run this script node patch-gradle.js.
Then build android tns build android.
This way it builds correct aar files for modules/plugins. This is a STEP in fixing issues, but not complete resolution.
